# jQuery: what is the best way to restrict "number"-only input for textboxes? (allow decimal points)

Tags: jquery, validation, isnumeric

What is the best way to restrict "number"-only input for textboxes?

I am looking for something that allows decimal points.

I see a lot of examples. But have yet to decide which one to use.

**Update from Praveen Jeganathan**

No more plugins, jQuery has implemented its own `jQuery.isNumeric()` added in v1.7.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186188/66767

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, but very useful. The opinion-based questions should be allowed. The person who is looking for this information only need to be aware that this is only an opinion-based answers. A TAG would be enough.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

## Update

There is a new and very simple solution for this:

> It allows you to use **any** kind of input filter on a text `<input>`,
>   including various numeric filters. This will correctly handle
>   Copy+Paste, Drag+Drop, keyboard shortcuts, context menu operations,
>   non-typeable keys, and all keyboard layouts.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/995193/1070129) or try it yourself [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emkey08/tvx5e7q3).

## jquery.numeric plugin

I've successfully implemented many forms with the [jquery.numeric](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/numeric/jquery.numeric.js) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

Moreover this works with textareas also!

However, note that Ctrl+A, Copy+Paste (via context menu) and Drag+Drop will **not** work as expected.

## HTML 5

With wider support for the HTML 5 standard, we can use `pattern` attribute and `number` type for `input` elements to restrict number only input. In some browsers (notably Google Chrome), it works to restrict pasting non-numeric content as well. More information about `number` and other newer input types is available [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/).

Comment: This plugin doesn't allow you to use backspace in Opera.

Comment: @Darryl the source is only a few dozen lines long, so I'm sure modifying it to allow that is trivial. I just found this plugin and modified it so that there is now an `allowDecimal` option for whenever I only want to allow integer values.. the source is very simple and well written.

Comment: This does not work when copy-pasting into input fields which are of `type="number"`.

Comment: @Tallmaris this is indeed very old question and answer. There has been a lot of changes to HTML and should be considered.

Comment: Hi @TheVillageIdiot, you are right. I did not want to sound rude in the comment (which is probably a bit dry) :) Fact is that I saw some recent comments, so I just wanted to clarify that this is probably, at the moment, not the best solution for the problem.

Comment: It blocks some jQUery plugins somehow

Comment: Another problem with this plugin is, that anything can be copy&pasted into the input field. You should be aware of that behavior! A quick hacky solution for integers could be attaching a change event handler with code from the answer below, which could look like: `control.val(control.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ""))`;

Comment: If you select a "string" near, and drag and drop inside the field, the plugin allows not numbers characters.

Comment: it allows the single qote like 123'09''

Answer (score 296):

If you want to restrict input (as opposed to validation), you could work with the key events. something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="numbersOnly" value="" />
```

And:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

This immediately lets the user know that they can't enter alpha characters, etc. rather than later during the validation phase.

You'll still want to validate because the input might be filled in by cutting and pasting with the mouse or possibly by a form autocompleter that may not trigger the key events.

Comment: +1 - I was going to suggest this same thing. It's a very good point to note that this form of validation can take place per keystroke, rather than once at the end. The only thing I'd add is some form of alert that what the user is typing is being rejected. Simply not showing the letters will make all-too-many people think their keyboard is broken. perhaps subtly change the background or border colour.. just as long as the user knows that your app is actually doing something.

Comment: agreed. i have an example at http://www.tarbuilders.com/. if you click "contact", the form checks the user input on the fly and if it's valid, there's a green border and check mark. invalid -> red and "x"

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11890073/573634) to fix the arrow key problem.

Comment: Please note that you can still paste characters and letters with a right mouse button click > paste. An easy way to fix this would be: `$doc.on('keyup blur input propertychange', 'input[name="price"]', function(){$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));});`

Comment: CRAP, if I write numbers i.e "123", and then press a letter key, i.e "a" it empty the input...

Comment: Nice, however this accepts multiple decimal separator.

Answer (score 105):

I thought that the best answer was the one above to just do this.

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {  
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''); 
});
```

but I agree that it is a bit of a pain that the arrow keys and delete button snap cursor to the end of the string ( and because of that it was kicked back to me in testing)

I added in a simple change

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    }
});
```

this way if there is any button hit that is not going to cause the text to be changed just ignore it.  With this you can hit arrows and delete without jumping to the end but it clears out any non numeric text.

Comment: For better performance create a var with replace result instead of running it twice.

Comment: `keypress` could be used to further simplify this, because apparently `keyup` and `keydown` trigger on any keyboard key, whereas `keypress` *only* triggers on "character" keys (thus *not* triggering on the arrow and delete keys). See this answer for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367720/1298685

Comment: It is accepting more than one decimal. How to accept only one decimal. I have applied for amount text field. It is taking 12.5.6 also.  How to restrict for one point.

Comment: @IanCampbell keypress means you can input a character to begin with that doesnt get removed. Won't work. Keydown does the same thing. I can only make it work with keyup.

Answer (score 54):

The jquery.numeric plugin has some bugs that I notified the author of. It allows multiple decimal points in Safari and Opera, and you can't type backspace, arrow keys, or several other control characters in Opera. I needed positive integer input so I ended up just writing my own in the end.

```
$(".numeric").keypress(function(event) {
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
  if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
      (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || // Always 1 through 9
      (48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value")) || // No 0 first digit
      isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
    return;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Its not possible to enter a 0 at all using this code. Tested with Chrome and FF on Mac.

Comment: I updated this in order to accept 0 digit    (48 == event.which && ($(this).val() > 0 )) || // No 0 first digit

Comment: This is a great solution but it's missing decimals, just add
  (46 == event.which && !($(this).val().includes("."))) ||

Comment: Can't type 0 at all.

Answer (score 49):

No more plugins, **jQuery** has implemented its own [**jQuery.isNumeric()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) added in v1.7.

> **`jQuery.isNumeric( value )`**
>
> Determines whether its argument is anumber.

## Samples results

```
$.isNumeric( "-10" );     // true
$.isNumeric( 16 );        // true
$.isNumeric( 0xFF );      // true
$.isNumeric( "0xFF" );    // true
$.isNumeric( "8e5" );     // true (exponential notation string)
$.isNumeric( 3.1415 );    // true
$.isNumeric( +10 );       // true
$.isNumeric( 0144 );      // true (octal integer literal)
$.isNumeric( "" );        // false
$.isNumeric({});          // false (empty object)
$.isNumeric( NaN );       // false
$.isNumeric( null );      // false
$.isNumeric( true );      // false
$.isNumeric( Infinity );  // false
$.isNumeric( undefined ); // false
```

Here is an example of how to tie the isNumeric() in with the event listener

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.numeric-only', function(event) {
   var v = this.value;
   if($.isNumeric(v) === false) {
        //chop off the last char entered
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1);
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 for no plugins. I would like to add a slight change to allow thousands separetor. In place of `var v = this.value;` change it to `var v = this.value.replace(/,/g,'');` . Numbers such as `21,345,67.800` are too considered.

Comment: Does anyone know how this checks for numbers? Does it use keycodes or regular expressions? Important if you consider different keyboard layouts.

Comment: This is very close. However, if you hold a character key down, it doesn't run the check properly. The character will "run."  Instead try this:

`$(document).on('keyup keypress', '#somethingSomething', function(){
 var aValue = $(this).val();
 if($.isNumeric(aValue) === false){
  $(this).val(aValue.slice(0,-1));
 }
});`

Answer (score 36):

The numeric() plugin mentioned above, doesn't work in Opera (you can't backspace, delete or even use the back or forward keys).

The code below in both JQuery or Javascript will work perfectly (and it's only two lines).

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.key-numeric').keypress(function(e) {
            var verified = (e.which == 8 || e.which == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^0-9]/);
            if (verified) {e.preventDefault();}
    });
});
```

Javascript:

```
function isNumeric(e)
{
    var keynum = (!window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    return !((keynum == 8 || keynum == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(keynum).match(/[^0-9]/));
}
```

Of course this is for pure numeric input (plus backspace, delete, forward/back keys) only but can easily be changed to include points and minus characters.

Comment: numpad is also not allowed

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) with its [number()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number) method.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI - number() doesn't work with exponential numbers.

Answer (score 19):

> No need for the long code for number input restriction just try this code.
>
> It also accepts valid int & float both values.

### Javascript Approach

```js
onload =function(){ 
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.number-only')[0];
  ele.onkeypress = function(e) {
     if(isNaN(this.value+""+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)))
        return false;
  }
  ele.onpaste = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

### jQuery Approach

```js
$(function(){

  $('.number-only').keypress(function(e) {
 if(isNaN(this.value+""+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) return false;
  })
  .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

**UPDATE**

The above answers are for most common use case - validating input as a number.

> But below is the code snippet for special use cases

- Allowing negative numbers
- Showing the invalid keystroke before removing it.

```js
$(function(){
      
  $('.number-only').keyup(function(e) {
        if(this.value!='-')
          while(isNaN(this.value))
            this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'')
                                   .split('').reverse().join('');
    })
    .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

Answer (score 14):

Below is what I use to literally block the keystrokes. This only allows numbers 0-9 and a decimal point. Easy to implement, not a lot of code, and works like a charm:

```
<script>
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }      
}
</script>

<input value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering- you can restrict decimals by removing `charCode != 46` from the if statement. Great answer!

Comment: Exactly, i removed the charCode != 46 to skip decimals. Thanks kaleazy, this answer worked great for me.

Comment: This is a bad solution because it doesn't take backspace, arrows,  control keys and other necessary keystrokes into account.

Comment: I just posted a solution which is similar to this, but also handles backspace, arrows and uses no hard-coded key codes. Check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23468513/838608

Answer (score 11):

As a slight improvement [to this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/891728/26510), you can use the [Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) with its [number()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number), [digits](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits), and [range](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range) methods. For example, the following ensures you get a positive integer between 0 and 50:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      digits: true,
      range : [0, 50]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You dont see alphabets magical appearance and disappearance on key down. This works on mouse paste too.

```
$('#txtInt').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: Although not allowing decimals, I found this to be the simplest method for integers.

Comment: For decimal, you could probably update the regex to something like `/[^0-9.]/g`

Comment: I don't need decimals. It was just because OP did, but yeah :)

Answer (score 8):

I first tried solving this using jQuery, but I wasn't happy about unwanted characters (non-digits) actually appearing in the input field just before being removed on keyup.

Looking for other solutions I found this:

## Integers (non-negative)

```
<script>
  function numbersOnly(oToCheckField, oKeyEvent) {
    return oKeyEvent.charCode === 0 ||
        /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(oKeyEvent.charCode));
  }
</script>

<form name="myForm">
<p>Enter numbers only: <input type="text" name="myInput" 
    onkeypress="return numbersOnly(this, event);" 
    onpaste="return false;" /></p>
</form>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeypress#Example
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/u8sZq/

## Decimal points (non-negative)

To allow a single decimal point you could do something like this:

```
<script>
  function numbersOnly(oToCheckField, oKeyEvent) {        
    var s = String.fromCharCode(oKeyEvent.charCode);
    var containsDecimalPoint = /\./.test(oToCheckField.value);
    return oKeyEvent.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(s) || 
        /\./.test(s) && !containsDecimalPoint;
  }
</script>
```

Source: Just wrote this. Seems to be working.
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjBsF/

## Other customizations

- To allow more symbols to be typed just add those to the regular expression that is acting as the basic char code filter.
- To implement simple contextual restrictions, look at the current content (state) of the input field (oToCheckField.value)

Some things you could be interested in doing:

- Only one decimal point allowed
- Allow minus sign only if positioned at the start of the string. This would allow for negative numbers.

## Shortcomings

- The caret position is not available inside the function. This greatly reduced the contextual restrictions you can implement (e.g. no two equal consecutive symbols). Not sure what the best way to access it is.

I know the title asks for jQuery solutions, but hopefully someone will find this useful anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the post Dave Aaron Smith

I edited your answer to accept decimal point and number's from number section. This work perfect for me.

```
$(".numeric").keypress(function(event) {
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right,decimal(.)in number part, decimal(.) in alphabet
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39,110,190];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
  if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
      (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || // Always 1 through 9
      (96 <= event.which && event.which <= 106) || // Always 1 through 9 from number section 
      (48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value")) || // No 0 first digit
      (96 == event.which && $(this).attr("value")) || // No 0 first digit from number section
      isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
    return;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
   window.jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
       function () {

           return this.each(function () {
               $(this).keydown(function (event) {
                   // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                   if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                       // Allow: Ctrl+A
                       (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                       // Allow: home, end, left, right
                       (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                       // let it happen, don't do anything
                       return;
                   } else {
                       // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                       if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                           event.preventDefault();
                       }
                   }
               });
           });
       };
```

And apply this on all the inputs you want:

```
$('selector').ForceNumericOnly();
```

Answer (score 4):

This function does the same thing, uses some of the ideas above.

```
$field.keyup(function(){
    var val = $j(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $j(this).val(val); 
});
```

- show visual feedback (incorrect letter appears before disappearing)
- allows decimals
- catches multiple "."
- has no issues with left/right del etc.

Answer (score 4):

/*
this is my cross browser version of 
[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery/995193#995193)
*/

```
$("#inputPrice").keydown(function(e){
    var keyPressed;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) keyPressed = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) keyPressed = e.which;
    var hasDecimalPoint = (($(this).val().split('.').length-1)>0);
    if ( keyPressed == 46 || keyPressed == 8 ||((keyPressed == 190||keyPressed == 110)&&(!hasDecimalPoint && !e.shiftKey)) || keyPressed == 9 || keyPressed == 27 || keyPressed == 13 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (keyPressed == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (keyPressed >= 35 && keyPressed <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (e.shiftKey || (keyPressed < 48 || keyPressed > 57) && (keyPressed < 96 || keyPressed > 105 )) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

  });
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 supports input type number with global browser support 88%+ according to CanIUse as of Oct 2015.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="askedPrice" id="askedPrice" />
```

This is not JQuery related solution, but the advantage is that on mobile phones Android keyboard will be optimized for entering numbers.

Alternatively, it is possible to use input type text with new parameter "pattern". More details in HTML5 spec.

I think it is better than jquery solution, since in this question provided jquery solution do not support thousands separator. If you can use html5.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p1ue8qxj/

Answer (score 3):

Just run the contents through parseFloat(). It will return `NaN` on invalid input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [autoNumeric from decorplanit.com](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) . They have a nice support for numeric, as well as currency, rounding, etc.

I have used in an IE6 environment, with few css tweaks, and it was a reasonable success.

For example, a css class `numericInput` could be defined, and it could be used to decorate your fields with the numeric input masks.

*adapted from autoNumeric website:*

```
$('input.numericInput').autoNumeric({aSep: '.', aDec: ','}); // very flexible!
```

Comment: autoNumeric is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 3):

If you're using HTML5 you don't need to go to any great lengths to perform validation. Just use -

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

The step attribute allows the decimal point to be valid.

Comment: Not so, Firefox & Opera allow non-numeric text input

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis you're right, it allows non-numeric text input but fails validation in FF (I haven't had the opportunity to test in Opera).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good way of solving this problem and it's extremely simple:

```
$(function() {
    var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

    $("input").on("keydown", function() {
        pastValue          = this.value;
        pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
    }).on("input propertychange", function() {
        var regex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;

        if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
            this.value          = pastValue;
            this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
            this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
        }
    });
});
```

*Example:* [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/10/)

**Scenarios covered**

Most similar recommendations here fail at least one of these or require a lot of code to cover all these scenarios.

1. Only allows 1 decimal point.
2. Allows `home`, `end`, and the `arrow` keys.
3. Allows `delete` and `backspace` to be used at any index.
4. Allows editing at any index (as long as the input matches the regex).
5. Allows ctrl+v and shift+insert for valid input (same with right click + paste).
6. Doesn't flicker the text value because the `keyup` event is not used.
7. Restores the selection after invalid input.

**Scenarios failed**

- Starting with `0.5` and deleting only the zero will not work. This can be fixed by changing the regex to `/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/` and then adding a blur event to prepend a `0` when the textbox starts with a decimal point (if desired). See this [*advanced scenario*](http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/18/)  for a better idea of how to fix this.

**Plugin**

I created this simple [jquery plugin](https://gist.github.com/dsherret/50d1a6ee93c8672da782) to make this easier:

```
$("input").limitRegex(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to check the contects of the text box whenever it loses focus.

You can check whether the contents are a "number" using a regular expression.

Or you can use the Validation plugin, which basically does this automatically.

Comment: The regular expression would be /^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/

Answer (score 2):

Check this find code for Database use:

```
function numonly(root){
    >>var reet = root.value;
    var arr1 = reet.length;
    var ruut = reet.charAt(arr1-1);
    >>>if (reet.length > 0){
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        if (!ruut.match(regex)){
            var reet = reet.slice(0, -1);
            $(root).val(reet);
        >>>>}
    }
}
//Then use the even handler onkeyup='numonly(this)'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet I've just done (using a part of code by Peter Mortensen / Keith Bentrup) for an integer percent validation on a textfield (jQuery is required):

```
/* This validates that the value of the text box corresponds
 * to a percentage expressed as an integer between 1 and 100,
 * otherwise adjust the text box value for this condition is met. */
$("[id*='percent_textfield']").keyup(function(e){
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(this.value,10))) {
        this.value = parseInt(this.value);
    } else {
        this.value = 0;
    }
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (parseInt(this.value,10) > 100) {
        this.value = 100;
        return;
    }
});
```

This code:

- Allows to use main numeric keys and numeric keypad.
- Validates to exclude Shift-numeric chars (e.g. #, $, %, etc)
- Replaces NaN values by 0
- Replaces by 100 values higher than 100

I hope this helps those in need.

Answer (score 2):

Found a great solution here http://ajax911.com/numbers-numeric-field-jquery/

I just changed the "keyup" to "keydown" as per my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Other way to keep the caret position on the input:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.numbersOnly').on('input', function() {
    var position = this.selectionStart - 1;

    fixed = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');  //remove all but number and .
    if(fixed.charAt(0) === '.')                  //can't start with .
      fixed = fixed.slice(1);

    var pos = fixed.indexOf(".") + 1;
    if(pos >= 0)
      fixed = fixed.substr(0,pos) + fixed.slice(pos).replace('.', '');  //avoid more than one .

    if (this.value !== fixed) {
      this.value = fixed;
      this.selectionStart = position;
      this.selectionEnd = position;
    }
  });
});
```

Advantages:

1. The user can use the arrow keys, Backspace, Delete, ...
2. Works when you want to paste numbers

Plunker: [Demo working](https://plnkr.co/edit/9QQKLATWzLVJYXqW1Rga?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I just found an even better plug-in.
Gives you much more control.
Say you have a [DOB](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/date_of_birth) field where you need it be numeric but also accepts "/" or "-" characters.

It works great!

Check it out at http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".numeric").keypress(function(event) {
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
  if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
      (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || // Always 1 through 9
      (48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value")) || // No 0 first digit
      isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
    return;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This code worked pretty good on me, I just had to add the 46 in the controlKeys array to use the period, though I don't thinks is the best way to do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I used this,with good results..

```
ini=$("#id").val();
a=0;
$("#id").keyup(function(e){
    var charcode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    // for decimal point
    if(!(charcode===190 || charcode===110))
    {           // for numeric keys andcontrol keys
        if (!((charcode>=33 && charcode<=57) || 
        // for numpad numeric keys
        (charcode>=96 && charcode<=105) 
        // for backspace
        || charcode==8)) 
        {
            alert("Sorry! Only numeric values allowed.");
            $("#id").val(ini);
        }
        // to include decimal point if first one has been deleted.
        if(charcode===8)
        {
            ini=ini.split("").reverse();
            if(ini[0]==".")
            a=0;                 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(a==1)
        {
            alert("Sorry! Second decimal point not allowed.");
            $("#id").val(ini);
        }
        a=1;
    }
    ini=$("#id").val();
});


find keycodes at http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple that we have already a javascript inbuilt function "isNaN" is there.

```
$("#numeric").keydown(function(e){
  if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))){ 
    return false; 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jquery.numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin works well for me too.

The only thing I dislike has to do with intuitiveness. Keypresses get 'disallowed' without any feedback to the user, who might get paranoid or wonder whether his keyboard is broken.

I [added a second callback to the plugin](https://github.com/Tabbernaut/SamWM-jQuery-Plugins/commit/01c2cc69f2deb5deb9473aa94d7f67b421503915) to make simple feedback on blocked input possible:

```
$('#someInput').numeric(
    null, // default config
    null, // no validation onblur callback
    function(){
        // for every blocked keypress:
        $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 100);
    }
);
```

Just an example (using jQuery UI), of course. Any simple visual feedback would help.

Answer (score 1):

i use that function and it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txt_Price").keypress(function (e) {
            //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
            //if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
            if ((e.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                //display error message
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used James Nelli answer and added onpaste="return false;" (Håvard Geithus) to ensure only integer is entered into the input. Even if you tried to paste, it will not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice jquery plugin called  [Jquery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) that designed to make masks on form fields and html elements, but you can also used it to simply define what kind of data could be typed inside of a field:

```
$('.numeric-input').mask('0#');
```

Now only numbers will be allowed inside your form field.

Answer (score 1):

Using Keypress Event

> 1. Array Method

```
var asciiCodeOfNumbers = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 54, 55, 56, 57]
$(".numbersOnly").keypress(function (e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.which, asciiCodeOfNumbers) == -1)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

> 2. Direct Method

```
$(".numbersOnly").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which < 48 || 57 < e.which)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code belongs to restrict alphabets in text boxes,have to enter oly number validate on keypress event.Hope it will help for you

HTML Tags:

```
<input id="txtPurchaseAmnt" style="width:103px" type="text" class="txt" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" />
```

function onlyNumbers(key) {

```
        var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode

        if ((keycode > 47 && keycode < 58) || (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8) || (keycode == 9 || keycode == 13) || (keycode == 37 || keycode == 39)) {

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***ALLOWS NEGATIVE NUMBERS ALSO***

Following code also accepts negative numbers

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="myText" />
```

**JS**

```
var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

$("input").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue          = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
}).on("input propertychange", function() {

    if ( this.value.length > 0 && $.isNumeric(this.value) == false && this.value != '-' ) {
        this.value          = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
}).on('blur', function(){
        if(this.value == '-')
            this.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this piece of code that does the job very well for me.

```
 var prevVal = '';
$(".numericValue").on("input", function (evt) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.val().match(/^-?\d*(\.(?=\d*)\d*)?$/) !== null) {
        prevVal = self.val()
    } else {
        self.val(prevVal);
    }
    if ((evt.which != 46 || self.val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) && (evt.which != 45 && self.val().indexOf("-") == 0)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 validation on your text inputs by adding a pattern. No need to manually validate with regex or keyCodes.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" />

$("input[type=text][pattern]").on("input", function () {
    if (!this.checkValidity())
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
});
```

For a solution with input [type=number], see my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798755/3616841)

Answer (score -4):

Please add in the bottom of the script:

```
if(this.value.length == 1 && this.value == 0)
 this.value = "";
```