# What's the difference between KeyDown and KeyPress in .NET?

Tags: .net

What is the difference between the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events in .NET?

Answer (score 355, accepted):

There is apparently *a lot* of misunderstanding about this!

The only practical difference between `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` is that `KeyPress` relays the character resulting from a keypress, and is only called if there is one.

In other words, if you press <kbd>A</kbd> on your keyboard, you'll get this sequence of events:

1. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A, Modifiers=Keys.None
2. KeyPress: KeyChar='a'
3. KeyUp: KeyCode=Keys.A

But if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, you'll get:

1. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
2. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
3. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
4. KeyUp: KeyCode=Keys.A
5. KeyUp: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey

If you hold down the keys for a while, you'll get something like:

1. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
2. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
3. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
4. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
5. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey, KeyData=Keys.ShiftKey, Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
6. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
7. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
8. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
9. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
10. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
11. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
12. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
13. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
14. KeyDown: KeyCode=Keys.A, KeyData=Keys.A | Keys.Shift, Modifiers=Keys.Shift
15. KeyPress: KeyChar='A'
16. KeyUp: KeyCode=Keys.A
17. KeyUp: KeyCode=Keys.ShiftKey

Notice that `KeyPress` occurs *in between* `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, **not** after `KeyUp`, as many of the other answers have stated, that `KeyPress` is not called when a character isn't generated, and that `KeyDown` is repeated while the key is held down, also contrary to many of the other answers.

Examples of keys that do **not** directly result in calls to `KeyPress`:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Arrow keys

Examples of keys that **do** result in calls to `KeyPress`:

- <kbd>A</kbd> through <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd>, etc.
- <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> (KeyChar='\t', ASCII 9)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> (KeyChar='\r', ASCII 13)
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> (KeyChar='\x1b', ASCII 27)
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (KeyChar='\b', ASCII 8)

For the curious, `KeyDown` roughly correlates to `WM_KEYDOWN`, `KeyPress` to `WM_CHAR`, and `KeyUp` to `WM_KEYUP`.  `WM_KEYDOWN` *can* be called fewer than the the number of key repeats, but it sends a repeat count, which, IIRC, WinForms uses to generate exactly one KeyDown per repeat.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thx, one caveat though, Escape does not trigger KeyPress on Chrome (not sure about the others).

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs:  Chrome runs .NET?

Comment: @PDaddy ups, I've overlooked, I've thought it was javascript :D but with slightly weird style :P nevertheless, it appears the rules are quite similar :DD ... funnily enough this answer helped me a lot anyway... cheers :)

Comment: @PDaddy I know that at least Tab doesnt fire KeyDown or KeyUp by default

Comment: @PsychoData:  That's because the Tab key changes focus, so it's not processed as input.  If you override `ProcessDialogKey` and return false when `keyData` is `Keys.Tab` or `Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab`, then you'll see the Tab key in (On)Key(Down|Press|Up).

Comment: @PDaddy I handled the `PreviewKeyDown` instead. It's working; I'm not going to mess with it anymore

Comment: A bit of an update. KeyboardEvent.keyCode, as well as keypress, are now marked as deprecated. You don't have to use keyCodes, you get the character directly. For example, event.key === 'a'. If shift key is pressed at that time, then e.shiftKey is true for that event as well.

Comment: @InvisibleGorilla: The question, and this answer, are about WinForms events in .NET.  Your comment is relevant to DOM events in JavaScript.

Answer (score 81):

The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the  KeyDown and  KeyUp events.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress

Comment: Most of the other answers are wrong in one way or another, but this one comes closest to the reality. KeyPress is raised only for character keys and it obeys the setting of keyboard typing delays/repeating. The actual sequence of events is: 1) KeyDown 2) for character key KeyPress one or more times (depending on the system settings and how long the key is held) 3) KeyUp

Comment: I don't have the rep to do it, but could someone bust a wiki and combine the content of the above comment and the accepted answer?

Comment: Filip Navara's comment isn't entirely correct.  If a key is held down, you'll get KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyDown, KeyPress KeyUp.  KeyDown is called for every repeat.

Answer (score 9):

KeyPress is only fired by printable characters and is fired after the KeyDown event. Depending on the typing delay settings there can be multiple KeyDown and KeyPress events but only one KeyUp event.

KeyDown

KeyPress

KeyUp

Comment: You're close, but off about the sequence.

Comment: @P Daddy - I've corrected it, should have double checked before going from memory.

Comment: @Stevo3000, fyi: non-printable unicode characters will also fire KeyPress events. I have an app that reads data inserted by a barcode reader into a textbox and the reader includes non-printable unicode characters.

Comment: @jlafay - Not according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) _The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events._

Comment: @Stevo3000, I'm not sure how the barcode scanner inputs text into a textbox but the KeyPress fires for special characters that it sends. The value starts with a non-printable character and terminates with a non-printable character. So I'm not sure how it's firing if that's true. Maybe I'll take a look at the .Net assembly that contains the events with IL Spy to get a better look at what is actually detected.

Answer (score 5):

KeyPress is a higher level of abstraction than KeyDown (and KeyUp).  KeyDown and KeyUp are hardware related: the actual action of a key on the keyboard.  KeyPress is more "I received a character from the keyboard".

Answer (score 4):

Keydown is pressing the key without releasing it, Keypress is a complete press-and-release cycle.

Put another way, KeyDown + KeyUp = Keypress

Comment: according to MSDN, the event sequence is KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyUp (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: @RobCowell Also, as jlafay pointed out KeyPress isnt at all dependant on KeyDown or KeyUp.

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> Key events occur in the following order:
>
> 1. [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)
> 2. [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)
> 3. [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)

Furthermore, KeyPress gives you a chance to declare the action as "[handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx)" to prevent it from doing anything.

Comment: FYI, KeyDown and KeyUp also have a Handled property that you may set so that isn't a between KeyPress and the other key events.

Comment: FWIW although KeyUp, like KeyDown, gets a KeyEventArgs parameter its `Handled` property is inoperative for KeyUp (`SuppressKeyPress` is also inoperative).

Answer (score 3):

I've always thought keydown happened as soon as you press the key down, keypress is the action of pressing the key and releasing it.

I found this which gives a little different explanation: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/649131-difference-keypress-keydown-event

Answer (score 2):

From [Blogging Developer](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx):

In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it is useful to understand the difference between a **"character"** and a **"key"**. A **"key"** is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a **"character"** is a symbol typed by pressing a button. In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent **keys** being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a **character** being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

**Note:** You can also try out the *Key Event Tester* (available on the above-mentioned site) to understand this concept.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 1):

KEYUP will be captured only once, upon release of the key pressed, regardless of how long will the key be held down, so if you want to capture such press only once, KEYUP is the suitable event to capture.

Comment: The `KeyPress` event is raised for every character generated from input, both in response to physical key presses as well as when the character is the result of the autorepeat feature. [How Keyboard Input Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-keyboard-input-works) documents this behavior.

Comment: You are right. I will update my answer. The correct answer is to use KEYUP which will be triggered once, upon release of one or more key hits.

Comment: While no longer wrong, it still doesn't answer the question that was asked. This is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest explanation:

I held down the 'd' key for a second and then released.

dddddd

the keydown event happened once before the first d appeared on the screen, the keypress event happened 6 times and the keyup event happened after the last d appeared on the screen.

Comment: damn, misread the question and got it into my head he meant javascript