# Autocomplete on Combobox onkeypress event eats up the Enter key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, c#-2.0

I have a ComboBox with `AutoCompleteMode = suggest` and handle the KeyPress event like so:

```
private void searchBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

However, it does not catch the `Enter` key. It catches everything else since the autocomplete dropdown works perfectly.

I also tried the suggestion offered here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/2db0b540-756a-4a4f-9371-adbb92409806, set the form's `KeyPreview` property to true and put a breakpoint in the form's KeyPress event handler:

```
private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

However, even the form's handler was not catching the enter key!

Any suggestions?

(If I disable the autocomplete, it catches the Enter key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Difference between KeyDown and KeyPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net)

In your case the best you may do is use KeyDown event.

```
void SearchBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Another interesting thing about KeyPress event is: it even catches Enter key with autocompete on if the combobox has no items! :-)

Comment: This solution also works for Delphi and the `OnKeyPress` vs `OnKeyDown` events.