# TextBox KeyPress event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, textbox, keyboard-events

I have a Form with nine `TextBox` controls. Each one has a `KeyPress` event handler that fires on Enter/Return and more.

The fifth `TextBox`(`Kategorie`) and sixth (`Ort`) don't fire. The others do. The code is:

```
private void tb_Kategorie_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("works");
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {            
        tb_Ort.Focus();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        tb_Kategorie.Text = escSpeicher;
        tb_Kategorie.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

The event handler is set in the Designer and in designer.cs. The button and the code are not copy/pasted. Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Is this method linked to the event? You can see this in designer view of the form. Click on the textbox and check what's written in the KeyPress field in Properties window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// You Can Use Key Down method here
private void tb_Kategorie_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("works");
    if (e.KeyCode==  Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode== Keys.Return)
    {

        tb_Ort.Focus();
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode==  Keys.Escape)
    {
        tb_Kategorie.Text = escSpeicher;
        tb_Kategorie.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

// try this

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `True`

Comment: Tried but doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

It is something with the Autocomplete Source.
This is the same problem like in

[Autocomplete on Combobox onkeypress event eats up the Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760791/autocomplete-on-combobox-onkeypress-event-eats-up-the-enter-key)

It is not really solved, but a nice workaround