# Why is this JavaScript not working? Any ideas

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Here is a Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EzLnH/. 
If I change the function to:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 77 && event.shiftKey) {
        alert('You pressed ctrl+m');
    }
});​
```

It works but the function in jsfiddle does not.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Keypress does not work for non-char keys.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaniging it to `$(document).on("keydown"...` worked for me.  You should be using .on now, .bind is deprecated in jQuery 1.8+.  The issue was the "keypress" part though, modifier keys don't get picked up by a keypress event so it seems.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzLnH/2/)