# JavaScript keypress in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, knockout.js, windows-phone-8, keypress

I'm trying to handle `keypress` event in Windows Phone's browser via JavaScript. Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/alex_myronov/c5n4C/2/. But as I change `input` value the handler is not triggered. It triggered only in case `inpu`t lost focus.
Does someone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this, I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try the keydown event as opposed to keypress, I believe keypress isn't consistently implemented.

```
<input data-bind="event: {keydown: changeStatus}, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
```

For more information on the difference between the two read here:
[What's the difference between KeyDown and KeyPress in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net)