# Holding down 'ctrl+enter' gives a different keycode for keypress event than just straight 'enter' - But only on Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have the following Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#foo").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(event.ctrlKey ? "Ctrl+Enter (13)" : "Enter (13)");   
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 10) {
            console.log(event.ctrlKey ? "Ctrl+Enter (10)" : "Enter (10)");
        }
    });
});
```

Foo in this case is an input box.

Under Windows, and Windows only - holding down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> modifier changes the keyCode from `13` to `10`. So if I do <kbd>Enter</kbd> v.s. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I see `Enter (13)` and `Ctrl+Enter (10)` in the console. Mac OS and Linux don't do this regardless of browser.

Why is this?

Fiddle to play with at http://jsfiddle.net/K6NhF/

Comment: In many programs they have different meanings. Often one is Submit hotkey while the other is for line break.
It should also work with Linux, at least it does for me. Tested the fiddle with Fedora 20 and current Chrome.

Comment: OSX is doing this for me. Chrome 34 on OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Perhaps it's a locale related thing? I got a few other people to try it out in the #jquery IRC channel and they reported getting `Ctrl+Enter (13)`.

Comment: This isn't just windows only. This is browser/program related. Went through this issue a couple years back. It may be a more narrow problem now, but keydown/keyup have always been more reliable. An answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net#1367865) explains the difference a lot better. Also, get more information about key events in JS [**here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html). Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVB3H/) for testing difference seen in key events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot of inconsistencies in different browsers, here's an article describing them
[JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Also there's a library for normalizing keycodes in javascript
[keycode.js](https://github.com/nostrademons/keycode.js)