# How to check if a key has been pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a features: when a user **held** pressed a key, a function A is called.
When a user release the button function B is called.

I need to make sure that first function runs only when the button is HELD. At the moment using chrome, when I keep pressed a button the function A is called repeatedly, and function B is running when release.

How is possible in java-script or jquery?

Comment: [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) and [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event

Comment: You can write function for `keypress` and `keyup` events in jquery.

Comment: basically I need to develop something like show hide password as in the login windows in windows 8

Comment: keydown and keypress....also in market

Comment: so what is the difference between key  down and keypress?

Comment: @GibboK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net. Also not really sure why you're asking this type of question if you know how SO works (which you evidently do from your rep/badges). The answer is a quick google away/in the related answers on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#element').keyup(function() {
});
```

or

```
$('#element').bind('keyup', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's keyup should be what you're looking for: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

You can bind it to input fields or the entire window, the latter probably being what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your app should react in every part of html page use below code:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
$(window).keyup(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

If only part of the window (like some div) use proper jquery expression like `$("#myElement").keydown`