# Keydown and keypress events gives different keyCode

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress, keydown, keycode

I've read through related answers and articles on Stack Overflow, but still doesn't get it:

On Chrome console if I add two listeners to output `keyCode` on `keypress` and `keydown` events I get different `keycode` when the key is lowercase.

When uppercase however, the `keyCode` appears to be the same for the two events.

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){ console.log('keyPress', e.keyCode); });
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ console.log('keyDown', e.keyCode); });

// Open your console  
// Typing 'a' in the result field outputs 'keyPress 97' 'keyDown 65'
// on chrome 42 console. Activate uppercase, and then typing 'A' outputs 'keyPress 65' and 'keyDown 65'

// Why ?
```

So is this normal behaviour ?

Comment: IRRC keypress isn't raised by all keys, keydown is. Also I think keycode differ between browsers.

Comment: It is normal, that's why there are different events, because they behave differently. "The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value" -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net explains it well.

Comment: Thanks for fast commenting ! Yes I understand they are different events, but the key is the same. That is proved in addition when looking at upperCase behaviour : the keycode appears to be identical.

Comment: @ShawnJacobson Thanks for the great article, I understand that keypress occurs after keydown, before input and before keyup. I am just wondering why the keyCode differs between the two when lowercase but not when uppercase.

Comment: Because keydown is only tracking the key itself, not the state of the key.  If you press 'A' KeyDown generates a KeyCode of Keys.A and if you press 'shift-A' you also get a KeyCode of Keys.A.

Comment: @ShawnJacobson ok I got it, sorry for being low to understand, the word state solved everything. If you want to answer I'll accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between KeyDown and KeyPress in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What's the difference between KeyDown and KeyPress in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/)… explains it well.  keydown is only tracking the key itself, not the state of the key.  If you press <kbd>A</kbd> KeyDown generates a KeyCode of Keys.A and if you press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you also get a KeyCode of Keys.A.