# Enter needs to be pressed twice to trigger, KnockoutJS with knockout.validation.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm building a form-page and I got stuck when I wanted to implement an "enter-key" function to trigger the validation and the method at the same time.

[Here's a JS-Fiddle of the example](http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/y3eo5v32/1/)

As you can tell, you need to press Enter, twice, in order for the method to trigger. I believe knockout.validation has it's own event binding, and maybe that's why

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: {'keypress': enterKey}, value: customer.telephone">
<input type="button" data-bind="click: sendCustomer" value="send">

enterKey = function (d, e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("enter has been pressed..");
            sendCustomer();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please include a full but minimal repro *in the question itself* too. That way if the link rots or jsfiddle is down your question will still be useful to future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between keypress & keyup. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net) can be useful.

So I have replaced the keypress with keyup

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: {'keyup': enterKey}, value: customer.telephone">
```

and it seems to be working.Hope this will be helpful to you.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y3eo5v32/4/)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I'm getting the old solution on your link (with keypress). Maybe it's cached on my phone. I tried chaninging it tho and it worked