# How to check a checkbox when caps lock key is pressed in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I trying to develop a program using vb .net that could check or uncheck a check box when the caps lock key is pressed. I used the below code to do the same, but its not working.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.CapsLock) Then
        checkbutton_caps.Checked = True
    End If
```

So what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Try changing `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.CapsLock)` to `Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)`

Comment: Try `If My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock = True Then`.

Comment: You're handling the wrong event.  `KeyPress` is raised in response to key combinations (where a combination may be just one key) that result in a character being produced for input.  The CapsLock key does not produce a character.  You'd have to handle `KeyDown` or `KeyUp`, which are raised in response to single keyboard keys.  That said, certain keys don't produce those events either by default.  Not sure whether CapsLock does or not.

Answer (score 2):

Both these code will work.

➤ Setting **`KeyPreview = True`**

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.CapsLock Then
        checkbutton_caps.Checked = True            
    End If
End Sub
```

➤ Without using the **`KeyPreview`** Property *(Simply, add this code to your program)*.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef Msg As Message, _
                                           ByVal Key As Keys) _
                                           As Boolean
    If Msg.WParam = Keys.CapsLock Then
       checkbutton_caps.Checked = True           
       Return True
    End If
       Return Me.ProcessCmdKey(Msg, Key)
End Function
```

**Tip:** Use this code to uncheck the `checkbox` when the key is pressed again.

```
checkbutton_caps.Checked = Not checkbutton_caps.Checked

'Instead of...

checkbutton_caps.Checked = True
```

Comment: I think you should put `checkbutton_caps.Checked = Not checkbutton_caps.Checked`, so it desactivate the checkbox when it is pressed again

Comment: Thanks @SuperPeanut added that as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Function GetCapsLockState() As Boolean
    If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

If GetCapsLockState Then
    checkbutton_caps.Checked = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Capital Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = Not CheckBox1.Checked
    End If
End Sub
```

Both `Capital` and `CapsLock` will work.

Also remember to set `Me.KeyPreview = True` either in code or properties.

This is useful study about [keydown vs keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net)