# Detect if key "delete" was pressed with angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, keypress

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.pressedKey = function(keyObj) {
    $scope.myKey = keyObj.key;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-keypress="pressedKey($event)"><br>{{myKey}}
</div>
```

I use the ng-keypress on an input for detecting if there was a key-event and which key was clicked. I need all numbers and letters and also the enter and delete key. Now, the numbers, letters and the enter works fine, but when I click the delete key, nothing happens. How can I detect it also with angular?

Thanks & cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ng-keydown` instead of `ng-keypress`:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.pressedKey = function(keyObj) {
    $scope.myKey = keyObj.key;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-keydown="pressedKey($event)"><br>{{myKey}}
</div>
```

You can read more about the difference between `keydown` and `keypress` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net).

Comment: Hi, it works thanks! I will mark it as correct as soon as possible! Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

it's simpler than that.

`keypress` doesn't detect the delete key. Use `keydown` instead and it will.