# Detect Ctrl+Alt+O key press in a ng-grid cell of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard-shortcuts, ng-grid

I am able to detect single key press but when I press 3 keys at a time, It doesn't trigger the event. Below is my code. When I press <kbd>delete</kbd> button, It detects but when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, It doesn't trigger the event.

I am trying to modify the `ng-grid` cell value and once It's modified I would like to restore the previous value on press of these three keys.

```
$scope.pressedKey = function (keyObj) {
    if (keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "delete") {
        console.log("Delete key press  Detected");
    }
    if (keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "control" && keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "alt" && keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "o")
    {
        console.log("Ctrl Alt O key press Detected");
    }
};

$scope.ng_grid_column_defs =
[
    {
        field: "A",
        displayName: "A",
        width: "**"
    },
    {
        field: "B",
        displayName: "B",
        width: "*"
    },
    {
        field: "C",
        displayName: "C",
        width: "***"
    }
];

$scope.my_ng_grid = {
    data: "$scope.data",//this data comes from service
    columnDefs: context.ng_grid_column_defs,
    enableColumnResize: true,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    enableCellSelection: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    rowHeight: 20,
    rowTemplate: '<div ng-keydown="pressedKey($event)" tabindex="1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">' +
                '<div ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
                  '<div ng-cell></div>' +
                '</div>' +
             '</div>',
    beforeSelectionChange: function(rowItem, event){},
    afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem, event){}

};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to get quick response, worth to post Demo in Plunker/Fiddle/Codepen with your ui-grid table, custom cellTemplate. It will save us a lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I absolutely don't know angular, so I won't talk about it, but

```
if (keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "control" && 
  keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "alt" &&
  keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "o")
{
    console.log("Ctrl Alt O key press Detected");
}
```

is a dead end.

If `keyObj.key` is a String, then its `toLowerCase()` returned value can't be `"control"` and `"alt"` and `"o"` at the same time.

Now, assuming `keyObj` is a KeyboardEvent, then you should have [`.altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey) and [`.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) properties attached to it.

So to detect *ctrl + alt + o*,

```
if (keyObj.key.toLowerCase() == "o" &&
  keyObj.altKey &&
  keyObj.ctrlKey)
{
    console.log("Ctrl Alt O key press Detected");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed response!!! 'keyObj.key' cannot be equal to 3 strings at a time. So checking that way makes no sense. That's really a dead end. What you added at last in your answer works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 points:

- You should use 'keydown' or 'keyup' events;
- You should check `event.altKey === true && event.ctrlKey === true && event.shiftKey === false` to detect if that CTRL and ALT are pressed and SHIFT isn't;
- You should check for `event.keyCode === 79` value to detect if key "O" was pressed. It's a number of key on keyboard and won't change if user switch his input language. If you need only Latin variant you still could check `event.key === 'o'`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && !event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 79) {
    console.log('CTRL + ALT + O was pressed');
  }
})
```

```html
Focus on this snippet and then try to press "CTRL + ALT + O" and any other combinations
```

Comment: You should have considered editing the other correct answer because your answers are essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you read my question. In my case the 'addEventListener' is not required as the key event is already getting triggered using 'ng-keydown' in my html code. Other than this the info is somewhat similar to the answer given by Kaiido.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question for [detecting key presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220874/detect-if-key-delete-was-pressed-with-angularjs) that indicates to use keydown instead of pressedKey. The answer by @Martijn Welker seemed to answer the other issue.

Comment: Thanks @Steven!!! I have used ng-keydown event only. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the code in a debugger to see what is happening?  Can you detect just the Control keydown, the alt keydown on their own?

Comment: Yes my code detects any key but individually. The combo of keys doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sure about one thing. I am struggling with this just because of ng-grid. If the ng-grid were not there then It would have worked properly.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, but looked at the other responses.  All I can think of is use the debugger, and press and hold the CTRL key to see where the code goes.  Then press the ALT key and see how the code comes into your program, and see what state the CTRL key might be in.  Maybe the state of the key has changed?

Comment: I will definitely go with your idea and will update here.