# Replace symbols not working on keypress event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have input where I need to delete non number symbols

Here is html of component

```
  <input
  type="text"
  tabindex="0"
  class="search__input form-control-md + {{ class }}"
  [value]="config.value"
  [required]="config.required"
  [attr.maxlength]="config.maxLength"
  [attr.minLength]="config.minLength"
  (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)"
  (input)="onValueChange($event)"
  (keypress)="onValueChange($event)"
  (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event)"
  #inputElem
/>
```

Here is component

```
    export class TextFieldComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() config: FormBase<string>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Output() onChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Input() class: string;
  configControl = new FormControl();
  @Input() set value(value: string) {
    this._value = value;
  }
  get value(): string {
    return this._value;
  }

  private _value: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onFocusOut(event) {
    this.onValueChange(event);
    this.onChanged.emit(true);
  }

  onEnter(event) {
    this.onValueChange(event);
    this.onChanged.emit(true);
  }

  onValueChange(event) {
    this.changeValue(event.target.value);
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  changeValue(value) {
    if (this.value === value) {
      return;
    }
    this.value = value;
    let result;
    switch (this.config.isNumber) {
      case true:
        result = value != null ? value.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") : null;
        console.log(result);
        this.onChange(result);
        break;
      default:
        this.onChange(value);
    }
  }

  onChange: any = () => {};

  onTouched: any = () => {};

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

My problem, that on `focusout` for example, this method `changeValue` is working well and it delete non number symbols, but on `keypress` event I see that on console I have replaced value, but on input, I still see letters. How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what exactly [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is doing here. The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down and examples of keys that produce a character value are alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys.

Examples of keys that don't produce a character value are modifier keys such as Alt, Shift, Ctrl, or Meta.

In the above case the keypress event won't invoke and will only be called when the character values are produced.

You should use `keyUp` or `keyDown` event to track things more effectively.

Note: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367700/whats-the-difference-between-keydown-and-keypress-in-net) link for the difference b/w keyup, keydown and keypress.

Answer (score 0):

In your component access input element using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('inputElem') inputEl: ElementRef;
```

Then to set result after replace

```
result = value != null ? value.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') : null;

// update input value
this.inputEl.nativeElement.value = result;

console.log(result);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vv8jfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)