# How to restrict "positive numbers" only as input to textbox (allow "-99" ONLY)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

How to restrict "positive numbers" only as input to textbox (allow "-99" ONLY) using jQuery validator plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[jquery-numeric](https://github.com/SamWM/jquery-numeric).**

See also: [jQuery: what is the best way to restrict "number"-only input for textboxes? (allow decimal points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all).

Answer (score 5):

**Without using any Plugin** you can easily do that by using below mentioned code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="returnRetailQuantity" id="returnRetailQuantity" />
```

**jQuery Code**

```
//for allow only positive integers
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#returnRetailQuantity").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            }
            else {
                if (event.keyCode < 95) {
                    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This helped me, but i also accepted tab key. `(event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 )`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest that I've used is http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/.

There is a simple javascript function at http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/jquery/creating-input-fields-only-accept-integers-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" id="num" name="anyname" min='0' />
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
var num = $('#num').val();
$('#num').blur(function()
    {
        if(num<0)
        {
            if(num==-99)
            {
                alert('Valid number');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Invalid number');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Valid number');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```