# onkeyup do nothing for some char

Tags: jquery, keypress, keyup

Well i have made this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".graduate").keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode!=8 && (e.keyCode<48 && e.keyCode>57)){
        //some code here
        };
    });
});
```

I want input ignore write anything except integer numbers..

I found this: but i don't know how to convert it into jquery code..
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress

```
function noNumbers(e)
{
var keynum;
var keychar;
var numcheck;

if(window.event) // IE
    {
    keynum = e.keyCode;
    }
else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
    keynum = e.which;
    }
keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
numcheck = /\d/;
return numcheck.test(keychar);
}
```

The above code doesn't allow me to use backspace..
Any help?

Comment: Another approach: check the value set in the input and if is not a number (regexp, isNaN, etc..), return the string in the input to its previous content.

Comment: @Alfabravo what about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all

Comment: Don't ask me, try it and tell us!! :D (didn't know the plugin, I did such validation by hand some years ago :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".graduate")    
.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var
    editingKeys = {
        '8'   : 'delete',
        '9'   : 'tab',
        '46'  : 'canc',
        '37'  : 'leftarrow',
        '39'  : 'rightarrow',
    },

    key = e.which || e.keycode,
    keynum = (key > 47) && (key < 58),
    keypad = (key > 95) && (key < 106);

    if (!keynum && !keypad) {
        return (key in editingKeys);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will "always" give you the keycode in `e.which`. You can safely use `e.which != 8` in your if statement inside the keyup handler. i.e..

```
$(".graduate").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which!=8 && (e.keyCode<48 && e.keyCode>57)){
        //some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not the problem..
The problem is what i must right until `//some code` to ignore everything excpet integer numbers -- return false doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp: http://jsfiddle.net/DSvkS/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".graduate").bind('keyup', function(event) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    });
});
```

`\D`means anything but 0-9.

or support `.` and `,` http://jsfiddle.net/DSvkS/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".graduate").bind('keyup', function(event) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, "");
    });
});
```

`[^...]` means anything but `...`:

`0-9` is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

`\.` is `.` We have to escape the dot using `\` as the dot means match anything.

`,` is `,`

Comment: The problem is when i put some char into input box..
I see it and the disapeared..
That's not good