# How can I implement numeric text box in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

This is very good sample, but using another framework (KendoUI): http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html

How can I implement it without another framework (only knockout.js+jquery)

EDIT:

I have to prevent non-numeric character entrance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by taking a look at the documentation on extenders, where there's an example similar to what you're looking for:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

You may also want to take a look at the documentation on custom bindings:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

---

UPDATE
take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/891749/418613

that might be the easiest way to restrict input to numbers only

Comment: First solution is not enough (I've edited question), I will try to implement second one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple trick... you have 2 inputs: one with the value unformatted (observable) and the other one with the value formatted (compute?).
make visible the one with the value formatted and the other hidden and on an event (click) change it, and viceversa on lost focus change the inputs.

Here is the source code of Kendo:
Formatted(visible):

```
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value k-input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Unformatted(hidden):

```
<input id="currency" type="text" value="30" min="0" max="100" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" class="k-input" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="30" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;"><span class="k-select">
```