# jquery entering only numbers in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to restrict entering alphabets and special characters in a textbox using jquery. Need to enter only numbers. 
How to implement using keypress() functionality in jquery for a text box in jsf?.

Code :

```
      <table>
         <tr>
          <h:inputlabel value="Actual"></h:inputlabel>
           <td>
              <h:inputtext id="Actual" styleClass="input-tex" value="#bean.customer"></h:inputtext>
            <td>
         </tr>
       <table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can parse it into int and check

Comment: Can you post the code of your [**current implementation**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are having issues with so we can have a look at it please?

Comment: have you tried to search for the answer first ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but I use:

```
    $('#parentobject').on('keypress', '#inputid', function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.currentTarget.value) == true) {
            var textlen = $(this).val().length;

            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, (textlen - 1)));

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in onkeypress function

```
function validateDigits(){
    var str = "54665";
var re = /^\d+$/;
alert(str.match(re)!=null);
}
```

it returns true in case it validate successfully otherwise returns false