# Allow only numbers and one dot(floating point values) in text field with keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to allow only numbers and one dot in text feild like 56.50, 67.00, 78, 98.05, .25, 0.50 etc

```
$('#psp').keyup(function() {
if number or dot
.............
.............
else
alert('oops...  just entered an invalid character');
});
```

I would be really thankful if somebody can help :)

Comment: use a regular expression, what's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: what is the best way to restrict "number"-only input for textboxes? (allow decimal points)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=\D*\d)\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: You need to make the dot optional. Otherwise, they'll never be able to type the characters before the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code which uses regex:

```
var num = "56.50";
if(/^(?=.)[0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/.test(num)) {
   //
}
```

Comment: It won't match `.75` for example.

Comment: updated my answer to match .75 and the like

Comment: Hmm now it will not match `75`

Comment: Hmm now it will match an empty string also.