# How to restrict only numeric value in input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my code i am restricting only numeric values into my input field for that i am using this code.

```
if($('.calculator #loan_Amount').val() != "") {
    var value = $('.calculator #loan_Amount').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    if(!intRegex.test(value)) {
        alert('Loan amount must be numeric.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

but now if i enter the value 6500.25 it says the value has to be numeric it is not taking the decimal digit as numeric. is any body having idea regarding it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all

Answer (score 4):

*`\d+` means one or more integers not floating number* and hence it fails.

## Using Regex

Try this `\d+(\.\d*)*` means

[image]

## Using jQuery

Since you already use jquery, so better go with [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

```
if($('.calculator #loan_Amount').val() != "") {
   if(!$.isNmeric(this.value) {
        alert('Loan amount must be numeric.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), it is possible to ignore keys other than digits. It can also allow you to do custom digit grouping (aka thousand separator) without having user to hit comma keys. Have a look at the Demo tab on [this page](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.calculator #loan_Amount').keyup(function(){
    var iptext = $(this).val();
    if(!(iptext.match('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')))
    {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

this will accept only the neumeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which blocks all non numeric input from being entered into the text-field.

html

```
<input type="text" id="numbersOnly" />
```

javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('numbersOnly');
input.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var k = e.which;
    /* numeric inputs can come from the keypad or the numeric row at the top */
    if ( (k < 48 || k > 57) && (k < 96 || k > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript **isNaN(value)** method which returns true if value (Not a Number) Otherwise false

```
  if($('.calculator #loan_Amount').val() != "") {
    var value = $('.calculator #loan_Amount').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    if(isNaN(value)) 
    {
        alert('Loan amount must be numeric.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps you.