# Dynamically changing form value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I would like to change the value of  input fields in a form based on the input 
of one of the fields live without refresh before submitting the form.

For example

```
<input type="text" name="chance" value="50">
```

Let's say a user inputs 80 into the field.

Would I then be able to do the calculation 1/input x 98 where the input = 80 (so it would be 1/80 x 98).

I would then set this as the value of input of another field in the form.

```
<input type="text" name="payout" value="1/input x 98">
```

Without refreshing the page. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On change of `chance` you can set the value of `payout` like this.

```
<input type="text" name="chance" value="50"
onchange="document.getElementById('payout').value='1/'+this.value+'x 98'">
```

If you want on that on the go without need of enter then use

```
<input type="text" name="chance" value="50"
    onkeyup="document.getElementById('payout').value='1/'+this.value+'x 98'">
```

```html
Chance: <input type="text" name="chance" value=""
   onkeyup="document.querySelector('input[name=payout]').value=this.value?1/this.value*98:''">

<br/><br/>Payout: <input type="text" name="payout" value=""><br/>
```

If you want to restrict the chance field to enter only number then check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287531/restrict-the-input-field-to-enter-only-numbers-or-digits-int-and-float-both#answer-30287532)

Comment: The problem with this is that it still requires you to press enter to update the entry of the other fields. In there another augment unlike `onchange` which will be triggered when a value is entered but enter is not pressed.

Comment: didnt understand the other values(payout) should only change when there is change in chance right? or do you want it on keyup?

Comment: Whenever someone starts to enter something in the field  chance, this number should also change live in payout. Cheers

Comment: Ok.. updated the answer with both use cases. check it out.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this did not work. What did work, was putting this script in jquery in the head. `$('#sidetextdyn').text($(this).val());` . How could I rephrase that to do 1 / thisval x 96 and then add the letter x on the end. Thanks so much!

Comment: can you create small snippet with your actual input fields, otherwise as you can check in answer snippet its working properly

Comment: Thanks man, works well! How would I apply this to something like a `<p id = 'test'> Text to change </p>`   . Also, what about limiting number of decimal places?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81318/discussion-between-vinayakj-and-semger).