# How to restrict the amount of numbers allowed in the html number input (live)?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

Basically, I have a number input field on my page, and I want users to only be able to insert **4** digits in the field. I know I can do something like this:

```
<input type="number" max="9999">
```

But the browser is going to check if the input is correct only when I press the 
"submit" button. What I want to do is : Let's say that the user types "1234" in the box, and after that he tries to type "1" or any other number. I want him to not be able to do that. Basically when he keeps pressing any of the buttons/letters, I want them to simply not appear in the box.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately `maxlength` only works with `type="text"`. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yq91ejox/1/).

Comment: @initialxy Interesting. I didn't know that. In that case I would probably use text and don't bother with number since it can't restrict the input.

Comment: @SebastianNette see here for a complete list of supported attributes depending on input type: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var numberInput = document.getElementById('a');

numberInput.onkeypress = function(){
  console.log(this.value.length)
  if(this.value.length>3)
    return false
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number">
```

For making it generalised, use below code

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.restrictLength');

for( i  in inputs){
   inputs[i].onkeypress = function(){
         console.log(this.id,this.value.length,this.getAttribute('data-restrict-to'));
         if(this.value.length>Number(this.getAttribute('data-restrict-to'))-1)
           return false
}

}
```

```html
<input id="a" class="restrictLength" type="number" data-restrict-to="4"> restrict to 4
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="b" class="restrictLength" type="number" data-restrict-to="2"> restrict to 2
```

Comment: For restricting the field to number only by not using `type=number`, please visit [Restrict to Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287531/input-number-validation-restrict-to-enter-only-numbers-or-digits-int-float/30287532#30287532)

Comment: It would be better to listen to the input event instead and then just cut everything off that exceeds the retriction. E.g.Copy&Paste or using those arrows at the input are not affected.

Comment: @SebastianNette valid point but see question `Let's say that the user types "1234" in the box, and after that he tries to type "1" or any other number. I want him to not be able to do that`

Comment: So If OP wants such restriction, OP can add extra code to do that using events like `change` etc, also event `input` is not broadly supported event

Comment: Thanks, that's the simplest answer that solves my problem. But something's not right. I can't write any letters in the box, expect the letter "e". I don't know why that happens. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: here `e` stands for `exponential` number so `2e10` is allowed as its a number

Answer (score 2):

```
var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        $(function () {
            $("#a").bind("keypress", function (e) {
                if(this.value.length>3){ return false}
                var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);

                return ret;
            });
            $("#a").bind("paste", function (e) {
                return false;
            });
            $("#a").bind("drop", function (e) {
                return false;
            });
        });

    <input id="a" type="number">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to use jQuery since I'm still quite a beginner in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input type="number" id="userNumber">
        <input type="submit" id="numberSubmit" onclick="CheckValid()">
        <label id="warningMessage"></label>
        <script>
            function CheckValid(){
            var number = document.getElementById("userNumber").value;
            if(isNaN(number) || number.length != 4)
            {
                document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "Invalid";
            }   
            else{
                document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "Valid";
            }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only checks if the input is valid when I click on the box.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet and simple.

```
<input id="a" type="text" maxLength = "4" 
onkeypress='return event.charCode > 48 && event.charCode < 57'>
```

Note: Solution based on a community wiki : [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: AFAIK this removes mobile support; several mobile browsers will pop up a number pad instead of a keyboard when they encounter `type="number"` and this prevents that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="number" max="9999" maxlength="4">
```

Comment: Unfortunately `maxlength` only works with `type="text"`. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yq91ejox/1/).