# Calculate Values OnSelect & Update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown selection field and other fields. It goes like this,

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
   Size</label><select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
       <option value="10">AAA</option>
       <option value="20">BBB</option>
       <option value="30">CCC</option>
       <option value="40">DDD</option>
    </select>
  </div>

 <input type="number" name="no_needed" title="" required id="id_no_needed" step="0.01" />
 <input type="number" name="total_price" title="" required id="id_total_price" step="0.01" />
```

Let's say a user selects AAA, I want to get the value of 'AAA' which is 10 and multiply by 'no_needed' field value inserted by the user and make the result insert in total_price field. Even if the user selects CCC it should follow the same process.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select').on('change', function() {
   $('.sr-only').text($('select[name=max_size]').val() * 
   ($('select[name=no_needed]').val()));
  });

 });
```

It's not working. I really don't know javascript. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You should ask a separate question rather than editing this one.

Comment: removed it. and fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element with name `no_needed` is an `input`, not `select`.

```
<input type="number" name="no_needed" title="" required id="id_no_needed" step="0.01" />
```

So your selector for it should be `input[name=no_needed]` instead of `select[name=no_needed]`.

Similarly, to select the input with name `total_price`, the selector would be `input[name=total_price]`. Also, since you intend to set value of it, instead of settings its `.text()`, you need to set `.val()`.

See the updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name=total_price]').val($('select[name=max_size]').val() *
      ($('input[name=no_needed]').val()));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
   Size</label><select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
       <option value="10">AAA</option>
       <option value="20">BBB</option>
       <option value="30">CCC</option>
       <option value="40">DDD</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input type="number" name="no_needed" title="" required id="id_no_needed" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" name="total_price" title="" required id="id_total_price" step="0.01" />
```

Also, you could set a change event handler on `no_needed` input to update the total price even if the size doesn't change:

```js
function recalculatePrice() {
  $('input[name=total_price]').val(
    ($('select[name=max_size]').val() *
    $('input[name=no_needed]').val()).toFixed(2)
  );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    recalculatePrice();
  });
  
  $('input[name=no_needed]').on('input', function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
      if(!isNaN($(this).val())) {
        recalculatePrice();  
      } else {
        $(this).val(""); 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
   Size</label><select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
       <option value="10">AAA</option>
       <option value="20">BBB</option>
       <option value="30">CCC</option>
       <option value="40">DDD</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input type="number" name="no_needed" title="" required id="id_no_needed" step="0.01" />
<input type="number" name="total_price" title="" required id="id_total_price" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't show the result in the total price field. No line of code on total_price field. Kindly check it again.

Comment: @YoYo I missed that in the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: How do I enforce the no_needed value to float like this 10.0 or 255.0, and the total_price to have 2 digits decimal like this 780.00 or 1000.00?

Comment: There are already some good answers about those points. For first, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287531/input-number-validation-restrict-to-enter-only-numbers-or-digits-int-float#30287532)

Comment: For second, you can use `.toFixed(2)` - to ensure that there are only two decimal points after the number. Try something like `var x=2;console.log(x.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Can you kindly update the answer in case other people might want the same.

Comment: @YoYo Sure, I've updated the second snippet in my answer. You can add `$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1));` after recalculatePrice in the `input` event handler to ensure that there is only one digit after decimal point for `no_needed`, but that got annoying to use, so I didn't add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm just getting straight up value. like 2400 instead of 2400.00. I've added the .toFixed(2). This was added to the total_price.

Comment: @YoYo Weird. Let me check that.

Comment: Looks like removing the `type=number` fixes that problem. But I am not sure why that is. Since it works fine on Chrome, it could be a bug.

Comment: Okay. let me change it to text and see.

Comment: Another question, how do I show the value of the option selected in a read-only field? Lets call the field value_me input type="number" name="value_me" title="" required id="id_value_me" /> So if a user select AAA it will show the value of AAA in the field value_me.

Comment: It could be something like `$('#id_value_me').val(INTENDED_VALUE)` or `$('input[name=value_me]').val(INTENDED_VALUE)`. You already know how to get the value of `select` there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158218/discussion-between-yoyo-and-nisarg-shah).

Comment: Hello @Nisarg kindly take a look at my updated question again.

Comment: @YoYo if you have a new question, then you should create a new question. StackOverflow is not a forum. Each individual question should be separated so that it is useful to others as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected option's value with `.val()` on the select. Then you need to convert the values of the select and the "no needed" input to integers or floats in order to multiply them.

I also added a fallback to `0` when no value is set.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#id_max_size').on('change', function() {
       var selectedValue = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0,
           noNeededValue = parseFloat($('#id_no_needed').val()) || 0;
       $('#id_total_price').val(selectedValue * noNeededValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_max_size">Max 
   Size</label><select name="max_size" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_max_size">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
       <option value="10">AAA</option>
       <option value="20">BBB</option>
       <option value="30">CCC</option>
       <option value="40">DDD</option>
    </select>
  </div>

 <input type="number" name="no_needed" title="" required id="id_no_needed" step="0.01" />
 <input type="number" name="total_price" title="" required id="id_total_price" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: How do I enforce the no_needed value to float like this 10.0 or 255.0, and the total_price to have 2 digits decimal like this 780.00 or 1000.00?

Comment: @YoYo: You could use `.toFixed(1)` for "no_needed" and `.toFixed(2)` for "total_price" - but that doesn't work with input `type="number"`, so you'd have to use a normal text input field and rely on a JS solution to only allow to insert numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes:

- You are using `select` to select an input--use `$('input')` instead.
- You can use `this` to refer to the relevant `select` element inside the event listener callback.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select').on('change', function() {
   $('input[name=total_price]').text($(this).val() * 
   ($('input[name=no_needed]').val()));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. Using some common code.

Here is a link to fiddle. https://jsbin.com/cemafiqapi/edit?js,output

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('select').on('change', process);

     $('#id_no_needed').on('change', process);

    function process (e) {
      var factor = $('#id_no_needed').val() || 0;
      var selected = Number($('#id_max_size').val()) || 0;
      $('#id_total_price').val(factor * selected)
     }

});
```