# Allow typing only float percentage value for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539768) link to allow type only float percentage value for input. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/10/) is original jsfiddle.

I tried to replace regular expression and use this `/^((0|[1-9]\d?)(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.00?)?)$/` or this `^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`, but it doesn't work.

edit// In my case only float number between 0 and 100 is allowed

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/74/)

```
var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

$("input").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue          = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
}).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^((0|[1-9]\d?)(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.00?)?)$/;

    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value          = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you please mention your sample inputs and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your re is that the decimal part requires the full stop AND the digit at the same time. That's hard to type ;)

Try `/^(100(\.0{0,2})?|(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{0,2})?)$/`. That'll allow the `.`without digits.

Edit: Changed re to not allow 100 with decimals above .00.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

the response of @SamWhan is almost correct, it's not entirely correct because it accept value like `100.` and `100.0`, to fix it change the regEx to

```
/^(100|(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{0,2})?)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this functions to allow only **numeric** values or **number, with max 2 decimal**

You'll need to give the inputs a `data-type="numeric"` or `data-type="decimal"`

You could also use HTML5's [`<input type="number" />`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-number)

```
$(function() {
    // allow only numbers
    var ctrlAltShift = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = true;
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = false;
    });
    $("[data-type=numeric]").keydown( function(e) {
        if( 
            (
                !ctrlAltShift && (
                    ( e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 ) ||
                    ( e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||
                    ( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46]) !== -1 )
                ) 
            ) ||
                ctrlAltShift && e.keyCode == 9 
        ) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }        
    });


    // allow only numbers with 2 decimals
    $("[data-type=decimal]").keydown( function(e) {
        if(
            (
                !ctrlAltShift && (
                    ( e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 ) ||
                    ( e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||
                    ( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46, 110, 190, 194]) !== -1 )
                )
            ) ||
                ctrlAltShift && e.keyCode == 9 
        ) {
            if( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [110, 190, 194]) !== -1 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if( $(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') == -1 ) {
                    $(this).val( $(this).val() + '.');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if( value.indexOf('.') != -1) { 
            if( value.split(".")[1].length > 2 ) {
                var newValue = parseFloat( Math.floor(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val( newValue );
            }
        }        
    });
});
```

It surely can be optimized to one function.

**DEMO:**

```js
$(function() {
    // allow only numbers
    var ctrlAltShift = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = true;
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = false;
    });
    $("[data-type=numeric]").keydown( function(e) {
        if( 
   (
    !ctrlAltShift && (
     ( e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 ) ||
     ( e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||
     ( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46]) !== -1 )
    ) 
   ) ||
    ctrlAltShift && e.keyCode == 9 
        ) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }        
    });


    // allow only numbers with 2 decimals
    $("[data-type=decimal]").keydown( function(e) {
        if(
   (
    !ctrlAltShift && (
     ( e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 ) ||
     ( e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||
     ( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46, 110, 190, 194]) !== -1 )
    )
   ) ||
    ctrlAltShift && e.keyCode == 9 
        ) {
            if( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [110, 190, 194]) !== -1 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if( $(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') == -1 ) {
                    $(this).val( $(this).val() + '.');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        
        if( value.indexOf('.') != -1) { 
            if( value.split(".")[1].length > 2 ) {
                var newValue = parseFloat( Math.floor(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val( newValue );
            }
        }        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Numeric: <input type="text" data-type="numeric" /><br />
Decimal: <input type="text" data-type="decimal" />
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but in this example i can type extended latin letters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A